# Linear regression for inference when logging regressor and target

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, inference

I'm looking at the relationship between population density (X) and ad impressions (y). These features aren't normally distributed so I log both to create a linear relationship. The relationship looks great once I do this.

[image]

[image]

My final goal is to add categorical features to the regression to see what relates to over or under impressing the population in certain areas. For example rural/urban, 4g phone signal, demographics.

My question is does logging the densities violate the inference on adding further features. If it doesn't what should I be careful of when exploring the data in this way?

Comment: You might want to consider Poisson regression which is often used for count outcomes.

Comment: dncnQ -- In the case where different counts have different "exposures" (presumably why you're using densities) they can be entered as offsets on the log-scale in such a Poisson regression.